# Неверно задаю массив в php запросе

Tags: php, codeigniter

Здравствуйте, уважаемые пользователи стака. Ошибка состоит с вытягиванием категорий с БД. БД лежит на хостинге, и выглядит она так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пишу я структуру с помощью фреймворка Codeigniter. Скрипт в модели вот такой:

```
public function get_cat() {
   $db_mysql = $this->load->database('zhaimakz_products', TRUE);
   $query =  $db_mysql->get('categories'); // моя таблица
   foreach($query->result_array() as $row ) {

       if (!$row['parent']) { // если нет поля blog_parent_id, то есть подкатегории
           $data[$row['id']][] = $row['title']; // выводим только назву категории

       }
       else {
           $data[$row['id']][] = $row['title'];
           $data[$row['parent']]['sub'][$row['id']] = $row['title'];
       }
   }

    return $data;
}
```

Вывод категорий:

```html
<?php foreach($blog_categories as $key => $item): ?>
                            <?php if(count($item) > 1): // якщо це під категорія ?>
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordian" href="#womens"><span class="badge pull-right"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
        <a href="javascript:;"><?='1'.$item[0]?></a>
      </a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="womens" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <li><a href="<i>Нужно поставить ссылки</i>/<?=$key?>"></a>         </li><?php foreach($item['sub'] as $key => $sub): ?>
      <li><a  href="<i>Нужно поставить ссылки</i>/<?=$key?>"><?='3'.$sub?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php elseif($item[0]):?>
<li><a href="<i>Нужно поставить ссылки</i>/<?=$key?>"><?='2'.$item[0]?></a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Выводит категории неправильно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте выборку формировать так:

```
foreach($query->result_array() as $row ) {

    if (!$row['parent']) {
        // категория 1 уровня
        $data[$row['id']]['title'] = $row['title'];
    } else {
        // подкатегория
        $data[$row['parent']]['sub'][$row['id']] = $row['title'];
    }
}
```

А в ответе выводить `title`, а потом перебор по `sub`

Comment: У меня по идее 3 уровня категорий. Я сейчас попытался, он ссылается на пустой объект. Undefined offset: 0 код ошибки.